# How to use my AngularJS module in to Angular (v5) project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

I've a project divided in several modules ('login', 'workplace', etc..). These modules have been developed in AngularJS. Now, I've to create a new module using Angular5 and using directives and controllers (e.g. toolbar, leftMenu) located in JS modules ('login', 'workplace'). Can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do this

Moving from AngularJS to Angular there are to many breaking changes, its a completely new framework.

You need to rewrite all your code from the module in angularJS to Angulars 5 typescript.

Comment: Not even using ngUpgrade?

Comment: Never used it but i thnk that just bootstraps it. Prob not worth adding more layers when you can easily spend a day rewriting a module to typescript. Front end html may take a little longer to sort out

Comment: The problem is that js module is a very big project that has own directives,  components, controllers and services and to rewrite it may require a few weeks.

Comment: Then that what you have to do, as far as  im aware there is no short cuts for this

Comment: Thanks for response